# applicationWillTerminate not called on termination in a XCUI test

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, xcuitest

Why isn't the `applicationWillTerminate` appDelegate method called when `XCUIApplication().terminate()` is called? Is there another method of killing the app that will call this method?

I need to run some clean up code that must be run by the app, not the XCUI test in order to clear a test user. Unless it is possible to access the instance of `FirebaseAuth` which is held by the app in an XCUI test, which I don't believe it is but will very happily be corrected!

Has anyone got a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new instance of the `FirebaseAuth` and signing that instance into the same account to complete the tear down work. Not pretty but it works.